# How to use User as foreign key in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

I have made a model which looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Commens(models.Model):
    publish = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    example = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

But when I run `python manage.py syncdb` , I get:

> ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field
>   books.Commens.publish:  auth.User

Where I'm wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have `'django.contrib.auth'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, of course i have

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: After "makemigrations" comes the same error

Comment: Try removing `unique=True`, you shouldn't need that because it is handled by Django internally.  Also, your error says the field `books`, but you don't have that field in the code you posted?